# Why datepicker show same month when change month on a first time on autoOpening second datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

1. Click on the first field;
2. select any day; (then automatic opening second datepicker)
3. click next month button
4. showing datepicker has flash, but month not change
5. after this, next month button (and prev month button) have work.

WHYYYYYYY ?????

[Fiddel Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FdfPY/5/)

```
$(".from_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 'D',
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $(".to_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $(this).parents('.span2').next().children().find('.to_date').focus();
    }
});

$(".to_date").datepicker({
    minDate: '+1D',
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the bug, it has something to do with opening the second datepicker from the `onClose` function, adding a zero delay timeout seems to work though:

```
onClose: function(selectedDate) {
          var $toDate = $(this).closest('.span2').next().find('.to_date');
          $toDate.datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
          setTimeout(function(){$toDate.datepicker('show')},0);
      }
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/FdfPY/31/)**

Note: I changed your code a bit, I optimized your `.to_date` selector and made it so only the corresponding input is updated with the selected date